# How to associate socket.io sockets in node.js app with logged user in web app?

Tags: django, node.js, session, web, socket.io

I need associate logged users in my django web app with their socket.io sockets in node.js app, because for real-time part of web i want to use node.js. Session data will be stored in database. I think i can access cookies in browser, so i can send to node.js app cookie value, that acts like user identifier, but i think this isn't good idea. Is there any other way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie can be accessed inside the `authorization` event. So if you're already using a cookie to store session authentication data, it's pretty easy to integrate that into socket.io. There are some pre-built modules for doing this sort of thing, like [SessionSockets](https://github.com/camarao/session.socket.io).

[This article](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) gives some insights into how to do it yourself. The most important section is exerpted below:

```
var parseCookie = require('connect').utils.parseCookie;

sio.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    // check if there's a cookie header
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        // if there is, parse the cookie
        data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        // note that you will need to use the same key to grad the
        // session id, as you specified in the Express setup.
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
    } else {
       // if there isn't, turn down the connection with a message
       // and leave the function.
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    // accept the incoming connection
    accept(null, true);
});

sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A socket with sessionID ' + socket.handshake.sessionID 
        + ' connected!');
});
```

Comment: can't be there problem when socket.io fallbacks to flash? Cause i think is very hard to tell flash send cookies.

Comment: it looks like this is just for express or connect middleware (node.js web frameworks). My web framework will be django (python) or zend(php).

Comment: @Krab, The code above does not depend at all on express or connect, except for the cookie parser. You could write your own parser if necessary. This should still work with flash sockets. Socket.io does an incredible job of abstracting away the inconsistencies between AJAX long-polling, flash sockets, and web sockets.